# Display and post comments on facebook photo from webpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photos, facebook-comments

We would like to use the Facebook Comment plugin (or something similar) on a website. The photos are being pulled in from Facebook to our site (built in PHP). We would like to enable commenting on a particular photo and post the comment back to Facebook. Addtionally, if a comment is made on Facebook, we would also like for the comment to display on the webpage.

From the website, we have only been able to get the comment to apply to the webpage, but not to the photo itself. Thus the comment posts on facebook with a link to the webpage, but does not display the individual photo.

Does anyone know how to successfully post comments on a particular photo from a webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Graph API, just do an HTTP POST to `https://graph.facebook.com/PHOTOID/comments?access_token=ValidUserAccessToken` with the correct parameters specified (such as `message`) as well as a user access token with the correct permissions specified.

See the `comments` connection of `photo` at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! We have tried looking at the photo api, however, we seem to be having issues with getting FB application to be the receiver of the request and obtaining the correct permissions from the user. Complicating things _may_ be that the photo is located in a group and not on a user's page or on a Facebook Page.

Comment: It doesn't matter where that photo is, as long as the user of your app can see the photo, the above is your answer.